# Why can I not reach my NAS from vSphere Client or SSH with vmkping?

Tags: networking, vmware-vsphere, network-attached-storage, openindiana

In VMWare vSphere 5 I have the following setup. Why is there no communication on vSwitch1?

vSphere Configuration:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

NAS Configuration:

[image]

Ping Tests:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your OpenIndiana system needs to have two network interfaces in order to accomplish what you're trying to do. In the vSphere client, add another Network adapter and address it on the 10.0.0.x subnet.

Make sure that one network adapter is assigned to the "SAN" network label and the other to the "VM Network" label.

One network adapter is so you can see and manage the storage VM on the VM Network. The second adapter is the link between the storage VM and ESXi so you can serve NFS.

Make sure your vSwitch1 has an MTU of 9000. vSwitch Properties -> vSwitch -> Edit -> MTU. – ewwhite 2 hours ago

[image]

Comment: I think it looks like you have a vswitch that is self-contained. You need something that is connected to it to see other devices connected to that switch.

Comment: ADD A SECOND INTERFACE TO YOUR STORAGE VM.

Comment: How are packets getting from san to vswitch0 or anything else?

Comment: Packets do not need to get to vSwitch0, in fact I was under the impression that ESXi communicates with NAS on vSwitch1 through vmk1. Everything here is virtual, there are no external boxes except for my laptop connected to vSwitch0 on vmnic0 on a physical switch. Obviously to be able to manage a vm all it needs is to reside on the ESXi host, since I can 'manage' isolated VM's which have no network cards just fine.

Comment: Did you check your MTU settings on the vSwitch1?

Comment: yep I posted them above in the question.

Comment: It's definitely the NAS VM. I tested a live linux dist on vSwitch1 and it could ping vmk1. So I just really love computers <:( I deleted and readded the network card on NAS and now it works.

Comment: While my setup works without adding NAS to vSwitch0 i will accept your answer.